# How to remove Boostrap default body style in a component.html

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, bootstrap-4

I have a angular widget directive with my own css. when i add my widget in a another application component it's overriding with Bootstrap default css/styles.

Here is my boostrap css
[image]

My question is How i can remove font-family in my **compoent**.css
I am trying to override, but its not working?

```
    body {

line-height: 1.15; 
}
```

[image]

I also tried with !important as follows, but still applying bootstrap styles

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: your css should load after the bootstrap.css... when you run the project localhost:4200 what is the sequence of the CSS files

Comment: @AkberIqbal, Added screeshot

Comment: you probably have a JS filter applied... change that to CSS please

Comment: No js filter applied. Please tell how to do?

Comment: Provide the full `<head>` tag where you are importing your style sheet & bootstrap

Comment: @ShakeerHussain: this is how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770176/

Answer (score 1):

Insert your CSS after the bootstrap CSS. If that doesn't work user !important to overwrite the styles you want.

example:

```
body {
   font-family:none!important;
   line-height: 1.15!important;
}
```

Comment: I tried as follows but still defautl styles applying  body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
}

Comment: I have updated the answer. You have to add "font-family:none!important;" if you want annul that property for all the page.